# Specify running python kernel in jupyter notebook from visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to set up my visual studio code so that I can run jupyter lab from a remote machine in order to have a stable and persisting working environment that I can (re)-connect to at will. To this end I'd like to start `jupyter lab` from a remote `tmux` session like so `jupyter lab --no-browser --port 8080`.

This all works fine, but sometimes upon reconnection to the remote notebook server my visual studio code doesn't automatically reconnect to the running `jupyter lab kernel`. This effectively means I am loosing all my progress and have to start a new kernel.

When I reconnect to the same remote session through my browser, I have fine-grained control over which kernel is connected. Specifically I can do `Kernel -> Reconnect to Kernel` to specify a running jupyter lab kernel hash (?) to reconnect to. I'm referring to this sort of thing that is being printed upong kernel startup in the console `Kernel started: bd33f794-3389-427f-bba8-646af06754ca`

How can I achieve this specific goal in visual studio code?